# How to read Environmental Variables from .env file in Firebase?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, dotenv

The easiest, multiplaform way to store environmental variables is by using `.env` file in the root of our project.

Now, the problem I'm facing is related to Firebase, more precisely Cloud Functions for Firebase. For all environmental variables accessed via `process.env.SOME_VARIABLE` I'm getting `undefined`, until the time of copying `.env` file to my deployment folder. In this case it's the default's `functions`, only then it works.

The question: is there any way to do so without duplication of the `.env` file? Across all my (`Angular` with `Angular Universal`) app I can access the `process.env.SOME_VARIABLE`, excluding the backend logic, which is 100% relying on functions.

I've tried to debug it

```
console.log(require('dotenv').config({ debug: true }));
```

Returned me something like `workspace/.env` in the `Firebase`'s logs, but couldn't do anything with that.

Some of my trials:

```
require('dotenv').config({ path: '/workspace/.env' });
require('dotenv').config({ path: join(process.cwd(), '.env') });
require('dotenv').config({ path: join(process.cwd(), './../.env') });
require('dotenv').config({ path: __dirname + './../.env' });
require('dotenv').config({ path: join(process.cwd() + './../.env') });
```

Always gave me `undefined`, unless the `.env` was manually copied to the deployable `functions` folder.

Comment: Meh for me it doesn't even work in the functions folder :( I also get undefined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Firebase CLI deploys everything in the functions folder at the time of deployment, except for node_modules.  If it's not in there for deployment, you won't be able to read it at all without somehow going off-host to a remote network location.  There is currently no way to make the CLI merge in files from other locations.  You could perhaps try a symlink.

> unless the .env was manually copied to the deployable functions folder.

This is probably what you'll have to end up doing.

Comment: Thanks Doug, you guys (Firebasers) have excellent support for questions on StackOverflow. It looks like for now, I do have to keep my naive solution?